# Function and delegate literals in D

Tags: type-inference, d

Reading TDPL about function and delegate literals (5.6.1)

```
auto f = (int i) {}; 
assert(is(f == function));
```

I've got an assertion failure. Is this assertion correct?

I tried the following:

```
int z = 5;
auto f = (int i) { return i < 5; };
auto d = (int i) { return i < z; };
assert(is(typeof(f) == typeof(d)));
```

Assertion is valid there. Actually f is a delegate, not a function even if it doesn't need a frame pointer to access local variables. Is this a bug?

Also, I do not understand how `assert(is(f == function));` should work.

I tried `assert(is(f == delegate));` but it was failed also. What's wrong?

I use DMD32 D Compiler v2.053

**UPDATE**

```
auto f = (int i) {};
assert(is(typeof(f) == delegate))
```

Works correct, although there is no reason to be a delegate

But

```
auto f = function (int i) {};
assert(is(typeof(f) == void function(int))); // correct
assert(is(typeof(f) == function));           // failed!!!!!
```

Miracle. It seems D2 is not ready for production use yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"f" is a variable. The *is* expression compares **types**. This should work:

```
assert(is(typeof(f) == delegate));
```

If you want to create a function instead of a delegate, you can use the function literal syntax:

```
auto f = function (int i) { ... };
assert(is(typeof(f) == function));    // should be true
```

If the function literal syntax is not used, the literal is assumed to be delegate ([Expressions, look under "Function Literals"](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/expression.html). This makes sense because D should not change the type based on the whether the body of the literal needs the stack frame (this would be super screwy).  EDIT: TDPL does actually specify that the compiler will infer a function instead of a delegate if it can, regardless of the "function" keyword. This seems like a poor idea to me, so this might be something that has been dropped.

As to why the is(f == function) doesn't work, this looks like a regression.

Comment: Note that you don't need `function int`; `function` is fine.

Comment: Thanks, just noticed that the OP didn't specify a return type, so I fixed answer to reflect the inferred typing.

Comment: I think what the OP is really referring to is that TDPL states that function literals are functions by default, and only delegates if they have to be. I'm not sure if this is planned to be incorporated into DMD.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question. It seems assert(is(typeof(f) == function)) is still failed for a second case. Pretty strange.

Answer (score 4):

You might find [isFunctionPointer](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_traits.html#isFunctionPointer) and [isDelegate](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_traits.html#isDelegate) helpful.

### Update:

See this, taken from `traits.d`:

```
template isSomeFunction(/+@@@BUG4217@@@+/T...)
    if (/+@@@BUG4333@@@+/staticLength!(T) == 1)
{
    enum bool isSomeFunction = isSomeFunction_bug4333!(T).isSomeFunction;
}
private template isSomeFunction_bug4333(T...)
{
    /+@@@BUG4333@@@+/enum dummy__ = T.length;
    static if (is(typeof(& T[0]) U : U*) && is(U == function))
        // T is a function symbol.
        enum bool isSomeFunction = true;
    else static if (is(T[0] W) || is(typeof(T[0]) W))
            // T is an expression or a type.  Take the type of it and examine.
        static if (is(W F : F*) && is(F == function))
            enum bool isSomeFunction = true; // function pointer
        else enum bool isSomeFunction = is(W == function) || is(W == delegate);
    else enum bool isSomeFunction = false;
}
```

I think it might explain some things.

In other words:

```
void main()
{
    static if (is(typeof(&main) T : T*))  static assert( is(T == function));
    static if (is(typeof(&main) U))       static assert(!is(U == function));
}
```

Comment: As everything in `std.traits` is!